# TYPO3 REST Extension setup

Tags: rest, typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to setup the [REST-Extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/rest/) v2 in TYPO3 8.7 following [this tutorial](https://restv2.cundd.net/Installation/). I included the 2 templates called Virtual-Object-Page and Virtual-Object-Content in my template. I made a new extension using Extension Builder 8.7 from Github with a simple model. I installed the new extension and made some Instances of my model in the List View on my start page. In the Typoscript of my template I added:

```
plugin.tx_rest.settings.paths {
    1 {
        path = me-kinder-child
        read = allow
        write = allow
    }
}
```

**Me** is the Vendor, **kinder** my extension key and **child** is my model.

When I'm calling `http://localhost/rest/` I get `The requested URL /rest/ was not found on this server.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path in the setup is explained being possible with several options, so perhaps try different configuration, possible is also `all`.
I don't see a fault in your setup, so the fault might be related to the server-file `.htaccess` or the extension `realurl` respectively the combination of both perhaps.

If you try it already with `realurl` or `cooluri` then disable that to get it running without first.
The `htaccess` file you can disable first too and enable it later again to adjust all requirements to each other.

Comment: Hi David, installing end activating **realurl** did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not about RealURL was missing in any way. I just did not clear a cache that got cleared while installing RealURL. I guess that the "Clear all caches"-button in the Install-Tool would do it too.